# Strange artefact in forest tree

Tags: errors, tikz-trees, forest

I'm getting very odd output from some of my `forest` trees.  Here's a minimalish example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\trace}[1]{$\langle\text{#1}\rangle$}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\forestset{
bnode/.style=
    {draw=red,
     thick,fit=(),
     circle,
     label=right:{\itshape bounding node}},
default preamble={for tree={inner sep=0pt,s sep=.25in}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[CP [DP\\{Who_{i}},name=SPEC ] [\ibar{C} [C\\was_{j} ] [TP,bnode [{DP_{k}},name=SUBJ,bnode  [D\\{a} ] [NP  [N\\story ] [PP [P\\about ] [DP\\{\trace{who}},name=TRACE ] ] ] ]  [\ibar{T} [T\\t_{j} ] [VP [VP [V\\written ] [DP\\t_{k} ] ] [PP [P\\by ] [DP\\John ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[->,thick,dashed,red] (TRACE.south) to [bend left=120] node[rotate=45] {{\large\textbf{=}}} (SPEC.south);  
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Something to do with `fit=()` it seems, remove that and the "extra tree" is gone.

Comment: The code compiles well in ShareLaTeX. No strange behavior nor odd output.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I'll go with that for the moment as a workaround.

Comment: @Cragfelt Interesting, do you know what version of `forest` and TeXLive  ShareLaTeX uses?

Comment: I just had a look at that, TL2016, `forest` v2.1.4. (I have v2.1.5 on my computer, with TL17).

Comment: @AlanMunn I do not know where I can find that information. I have made some research but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Cragfelt No worries, Torbjorn has already commented on the difference.

Comment: What's the `fit` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: That is, as far as I know, `fit` takes 3 possible values: `tight`, `band` or `rectangle`. So I don't know what `fit=()` is intended to do. I ran the code on OverLeaf, since people say that works, and it seems to do nothing.

Comment: @cfr According to [forest documentation, page 9](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) "fitting library (automatically loaded by Forest) computes the
smallest rectangle containing the node, its first child and its last grandchild" (paraphrased).

Comment: @cfr Hmm. I'm not quite sure now what it was doing there. Fit can also take a set of nodes, one of which can be `()`. Maybe the actual artefact is in my code. :) Interesting result though, so I'd still like to figure out why it has the effect it does.

Comment: @Cragfelt Yes. `/tikz/fit to` depends on the `fit` library. That library defines `fit`. But Forest defines `fit`, so it will not be passed to Ti*k*Z. Rather, Forest will try to make sense of it in terms of its definition.

Comment: @AlanMunn I know, but Ti*k*Z keys only apply if unknown to Forest. Unknown keys are passed on. If Forest recognises the key, it will do whatever its definition tells it to do. So, in this case, `fit` is going to be processed by Forest. If you don't want that, you'd need to make sure it does not get processed by Forest's own code.

Comment: It is some kind of interaction between underscores and fit. gb4 is making the underscores active or changing the cat codes, right? But Forest relies on underscores having their normal cat code, I think. For example, these are used to replace spaces in key names.

Comment: @AlanMunn Try `\begin{forest}
  for tree=draw
  [A
    [B_y, fit=()]
    [C]
  ]
\end{forest}` with `gb4e` loaded to see the problem and/or grep `forest.sty` for `_`. Actually, you don't even need `gb4e` loaded to get a problem with `fit=()`. However, you do need it for the duplication effects.

Comment: @cfr That gives me an error with or without `gb4e`.

Comment: I think the real solution here is to use `\noautomath` for Forest environments. Certainly for those which include underscores in their specifications, but safest would be to do it anyway. True, it seems to work in other cases, but it is going to be very fragile.

Comment: @cfr If I replace all the bare underscores with `$_{...}$` and turn off automath it still gives the extra tree.

Comment: @AlanMunn Well what is `fit=()` meant to do?

Comment: @cfr As I said, it appears to be an artefact in my code.  But I'm still interested in what's actually going on anyway.

Comment: You are trying to plug `()` into things like `\csname forest@getboth\forestove{fit}edgesofpath\endcsname`.

Comment: As far as I see, using (`gb4e`'s) underscores in `forest` trees is safe. `gb4e` should be loaded after `forest`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fit` is `tikz`'s key in `/tikz` namespace. `Forest` implements `fit to` in `/tikz` namespace, which `fit`s to nodes visited in a given nodewalk.

OP's definition of `bnode` doesn't work because it tries to `fit` a `forest` node, i.e. a node that is positioned by `forest`.  Furthermore, it tries to size/position it in terms of itself: `fit=()` is processed while typesetting the node and `()` refers to the current `forest` node, i.e. the "calling" node itself.  (Note that the code wouldn't work even if there was no self-reference, as each `forest` node is typeset "alone" and only later positioned in the correct location. One cannot refer to other `forest` nodes when a `forest` node is typeset.)

Both `tikz`'s `/tikz/fit` and `forest`'s `/tikz/fit to` are meant to be used in "normal" `tikz` nodes, i.e. nodes *not* positioned by `forest`. So, the definition of `bnode` should be the following.

```
bnode/.style={
  tikz+={
    \node[draw=red,thick,fit=(),circle,
          label=right:{\itshape bounding node}]{};
  }
},
```

This works because the `tikz` code is executed after the node is already drawn (actually, all nodes are). But `forest` knows which forest node the code originates from, and `()` refers to that node. (Note that `forest` hacks into `tikz` implicit coordinate system to make this reference possible; package option `tikzcshack` disables the hack.)

In this example, the "normal" `fit` is quite enough for the job, but one could use `fit to` as well, like this:

```
bnode/.style={
  tikz+={
    \node[draw=red,thick,fit to=current,circle,
          label=right:{\itshape bounding node}]{};
  }
},
```

This could be easily modified to have the circle contain both the node and its parent, for example:

```
bnode/.style={
  tikz+={
    \node[draw=red,thick,fit to={current,parent},circle,
          label=right:{\itshape bounding node}]{};
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sašo. I think what happened was my original code used `tikz+` but simplified it with the resulting leftover `fit=()`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Which is what I was trying to say, too. (Less the details about Forest's node-building.) But I still suspect that having underscores active in `forest` isn't a good idea. Sašo, is that really safe?

Comment: Off-topic: definition of `repeat` on page 61 is incorrect, I think. The first argument is evaluated as Forest math and not pgfmath (except that that's the default).

Comment: @cfr  I routinely use active underscores in forest trees as I'm sure do (under)scores :) of linguists without any problems.

Comment: @AlanMunn I guess with Forest math you can avoid them now by just avoiding pgfmath in those cases. Or are you saying it doesn't matter when you use them in Forest keys either? `n_children` or whatever?

Comment: @cfr No, things like `n_children` will not work. But most of us who use `gb4e` on a regular basis are aware of the potential downsides, but subscripts are so widely used in syntax that it's worth the price. And it's easy to turn off selectively when needed. Also, our trees needs are really quite simple most of the time, so all the fancy stuff that you are so good at isn't usually necessary.